# .zip folder not showing up on TWRP

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing

I have a boot animation .zip file under \system\media on my phone, but the media folder isn't showing up under system when in TWRP. Why can't I see the .zip file in TWRP when it's visible in Root Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the problem was - "System" under "Mount" in TWRP was unchecked. After checking that, the folders under system appeared.